# Switch Mail off and get email only from selected contacts

Tags: osx-lion, apple-mail

In the email program Mail from OS X Lion, is it possible to switch it off so you only get email notifications for certain selected users? I thought about moving all incoming email to another folder (not inbox) and mark it as unread, but how do I filter the contacts I want in an easy way or is it there any other better approach!?